# Sending values from SharePoint list to Power BI Desktop

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

How can I sent values from a Share Point list to Power BI Desktop as a Parameters or whatever ,I've tried few ways like embedding values in links but it is not working , can someone explain it to me how can i do this ?

Comment: Where are you showing your report? Are you using powerbi desktop or online to show it or you are embedding report to some another tool like dynamics 365 or 3rd party.

Comment: I want to display values on Power BI Desktop

Comment: I don't know , how I can send values from share point

Comment: So how about you fetch your data from sharepoint into powerbi and then add filter on your visualization. By the way how you want your parameter I mean what is the use case of your parameter?

Comment: Actually I am sending an ID No from share point list and then on the basis of that ID No i want to fetch data from my tables and create a report in Power BI Desktop

Comment: No you cannot do that. You can add some criteria to fetch data from sharepoint but that criteria will be static, for ex Id=1 shall be the criteria but you cannot directly add this criteria to sharepont and that too dynamic. You first need to load data into powerbi dataset so you will have records with all IDS and then you can add filters/slicers in powerbi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot do that. You can add some criteria to fetch data from sharepoint but that criteria will be static, for ex Id=1 shall be the criteria but you cannot directly add this criteria to sharepont and that too dynamic. You first need to load data into powerbi dataset so you will have records with all IDS and then you can add filters/slicers in powerbi

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in Power BI work more like global variables rather than what you are used to in other tools. They are an excellent way to externalize references.

If you set a filter in Power Query for a specific subset of records, this filter will be folded (run at the datasource) rather than after the fact. Order is important when executing PQ commands for folding to occur.

I show this filtering in the video associated to my blog post here: https://marqueeinsights.com/how-to-data-mine-a-sharepoint-list-with-power-bi/ I’m doing a series of posts that are SharePoint/PBI specific since the interaction between them is poorly documented.

Also, is your need user based? If so, take a look at RLS. This enables you to do dynamic filtering automatically, based on the viewing user’s profile.

Hope this helps!
Treb Gatte
Microsoft Power BI MVP